# Locking pages with session WITH redirect to login.php

Tags: php, mysql, session, redirect

I have a problem with locking the page with session AND I have to
let it redirect to login.php if not logged in

This is the script I have and I´ve tried many of them and somehow none of them works

```
<?PHP
include("include/session.php");
?>

<?PHP
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
   unset($_SESSION['logged_in']);
else
{
    header ("location: login.php"); 
}

?>

<?PHP
if($session->logged_in){
?>
```

This code did worked at sometime but it didn´t redirect my to the login.php

This is the code on frontpage and every subpage where the page is locked 
so makeing attempt to access it should redirect to the login.php

Any suggestions?

Comment: is there a reason to unset `logged_in` if it is already set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either there are quite a few things wrong with your code, or I misunderstand the question_

- `if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){` ends with an unbalanced bracket
- Why do you `unset()` the logeed-in status, if you read it from the session?
- is `if($session->logged_in)` the same as `if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))` ?

Anyway, what I suggest is

- Change `header ("location: login.php");` to `header ("Location: login.php");`, some browsers might be picky with the caps
- Reduce the mess to

,

```
<?php
include("include/session.php");
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in']))
{
?>

<!-- whatever you wanna do -->


<?php
}
else
{
    header ("Location: login.php"); 
    exit;
}
?>
```

And make absolutely sure, nothing (especially no line breaks or whitespace) are ouptut in `include/session.php`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `login.php` is in path; is it in the same folder?

You should not have to unset the `logged_in`.

Anyway, if that does not solve it, post full `session.php` and we shall look into it.

Comment: Maybe I have to have full url because I have a .htaccess file on the server

Comment: @IngþórIngólfsson That should generally not be a problem. What's the location of `login.php` and the other pages?